# Dissecting/dividing "response" variable from console.log(response) using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Assuming that I am using jQuery.ajax();

the first parameter in the $.ajax 'success' callback is what returned from the server side.

```
function afterSuccess(response /** this is what returned from my server **/ ) {
    console.log(response);
    //Using reponse to print out something from the server
    $("#something").html(response);
}
```

`response` will print out everything echoed in the php file. How can I split each echoed variable in php and print it individually.

I was thinking of splitting `response` into `resp1` `resp2` `resp3` and `resp4`, and eventually I can use each outcome.

Comment: Try with `jQuery.each()` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ `$.each(response, function(i, data) { console.log(data) });`

Comment: What does the response look like?

Comment: It is just a couple of strings. Like in my php file: echo $one = "Stack"; echo $two = "Over"; echo $three = "Flow";

Comment: Check my answer, it will solve your problem. Put them in an array first, $data = array('one' => $one, 'two' => $two, 'three' => $three), and you will be able to access response.one, response.two and response.three.

Comment: @georgechalhoub Definitely use json.

Comment: @JasonP okay Jason ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use JSON format.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    type: 'json'
    ...
});
```

And in your php file :

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

Where data is your array.
Then you will get a JSON object as response, which you can manipulate to print either variable.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.each()` is an iterator. It will do exactly what you want.

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

```
function afterSuccess(response) {

    $.each(response, function(i,data) {

        console.log(i,data);
    });
}
```